# Why doesn't Jessica Jones ever "jump"?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, jessica-jones

In Season 2 of *Marvel's Jessica Jones* there were several instances where she need to go somewhere/escape somewhere fast and each time we see her running on foot, or taking a car. For example:

> Trish is in the hospital recovering after the IGH medical procedure. Jessica is trying to get to the hospital because she believes her mother will try to attack Trish. Jessica is riding with the cops and gets caught behind a traffic jam. She kicks open the door and starts *running* to the hospital. Later we see Jessica's mother climbing in through the hospital window, i.e. the fast way to get to Trish, i.e. the same way Jessica could have gone if she used her powers.

Another example:

> Trish is brought to the morgue to recover in "safety". Jessica is told to stay put by the cops. She makes it outside and then... hides in a body bag to escape in the back of a truck instead of jumping over a 10 ft high fence.

Why isn't Jessica using her powers in these life-and-death situations? It was established in Season 1 that she can jump incredibly high and far. Even in this season we see her sitting on the side of a building while scoping out the rival PI firm, which she clearly could only reach by super-jumping.

Am I missing something here? Is there a reason for Jessica not jumping in these critical situations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is based on a [Season 1](http://www.eonline.com/news/680989/aka-jessica-jones-boss-can-t-believe-marvel-s-daredevil-didn-t-get-a-stunt-emmy-nomination-either) interview but since it's the same crew, it must still hold weight:

> "She doesn't fly but she can jump many stories, and ***she lands really badly, which is why she doesn't do it too often***," Rosenberg says. "And the less you see it, the more believable it is. There will be flights in every episode and they'll get bigger and bigger and bigger but that's not my priority. That's not the nature of the story. This show is more character driven than anything like a scene in that universe."

So in-universe, she can't control her landing while jumping, she would be doing *more harm than good* while trying to save someone...

Answer (score 1):

She does jump, but not very often:

- She jumps over very high (about 4-5 meter fence) surrounding the gold club;
- In the first episode she is hiding in the huge metal logo on top of the building - she quite probably jumped there;
- In the last episode she jumps down from the Ferris wheel.

So she does jump, but not as high (or often) as Alisa, who is much stronger than Jessica.